# NServicebus - Stopping a long running process?

Tags: nservicebus

Here is my application I'm attempting to put together using NServiceBus:

- I have a 1000 files that need to be processed by a service.  So far I'm thinking I'd have one endpoint, the client, find all of those files and send them out on the bus to be processed
- My other endpoint, the server that does the processing, would listen for these client messages, when one comes in process the file, and return the results.
- Client takes the results, marks the file as processed, and waits for the next 999 files to be processed.  Client doesn't care the order of the messages that come back, just as long as they all get processed at some point.  (In reality the client is going to do something more with the data after it is processed that can't be done by the server, so I can't just fire and forget the request for processing.)
- Since processing a single message can take over an hour I would scale out the application to have multiple servers all attempting to eat through the 1000 files that need to be processed.

Conceptually, its like building a personal SETI at home service to run on all of my servers.

The issues I'm having is, how do I stop midway through processing the 1000 files?

- I want to keep all of my servers working as much as they can on my data, so when the client starts does it publish a 1000 commands for the 1000 files to process and then sit back and wait?  And if it does this, and decides to stop, how can it clear the bus of all of those commands to process files?
- If my client only pushes one or two messages on the bus at a time I could easily stop sending messages if I decide to stop on the client, but then I have two other problems

  1. The servers could be underutilized and I'd end up with idle servers.
  2. How do I stop the servers that are loaded up and processing data?  Send them a second command of a different message format?

Thoughts, ideas?  Am I approaching this problem using the right tool/right methodology?

Answer (score 1):

One of things you might want to think about is how you are going to correlate the message processing. I would use a saga for this and have the client generate some kind of batch id which is attached to all the files to be processed. This allows your client to be able to send a CancelProcessing message to the saga, the handler for which could then stop the processing / sending of messages to the file processing endpoints and perform any clean-up operations such as completing the saga and removing data from the database.

So you would have client endpoint, saga endpoint and one or more file processing endpoints (which would sit behind a distributor). Your client would be responsible for initiating / sending the files to the saga. The saga manages the file correlation and processing activities, while your processing endpoints focus doing the work.

Remember that the processing endpoints don't necessarily have to be physical endpoints. You can have many of these on one server if you wanted to and use monitoring tools to determine whether or not you need to add or remove nodes.